# postgres substring regex multiple results

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, substring

I'm trying to find image tags urls in a text field with multiple instances.

I'm currently using this code to extract the URL from the text field:

```
SUBSTRING(text_field FROM 'src="([^"]*).*')
```

The problem is it only returns the first instance of a image tag.

Is there a way to return multiple instances of matching from a single query?

Answer (score 5):

Use the function `regexp_matches()` with the `'g'` flag, example:

```
with my_table(text_field) as (
    values ('src="first";src="second"')
)

select match[1] as result
from my_table
cross join lateral regexp_matches(text_field, 'src="([^"]*)', 'g') as match

 result 
--------
 first
 second
(2 rows)
```

Read about [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in the documentation.